# Unit testing levels of classes with Nunit and Nmock

Tags: c#, nunit, nmock

I have levels of classes and interfaces, namely `Level1`, `Level2` and `Level3`.
Class `Level1` depends on class `Level2` and class `Level2` depends on class `Level3`.

Here is the code for that design:

```
public interface ILevel1
{
    string GetData();
}

public class Level1 : ILevel1
{
    ILevel2 level2;
    public Level1(ILevel2 level2)
    {
        this.level2 = level2;
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        // some more process on data.
        var data = level2.GetDataAndProc();
        data = data + ",Proc at Level1";
        return data;
    }
}

public interface ILevel2
{
    string GetDataAndProc();        
}

public class Level2 : ILevel2
{    
    ILevel3 level3;
    public Level2(ILevel3 level3)
    {
        this.level3=level3;
    }

    public string GetDataAndProc()
    {
        var data=level3.GetDataFromDB();
        // processing on the data from db.
        data=data+ " Processed at level2";
        return data;
    }
}

public interface ILevel3
{
    string GetDataFromDB();
}

public class Level3 : ILevel3
{
   public string GetDataFromDB()
   {
       // Functionalities to get data from db.
       return "DB Data";
   }
}
```

Now, I can unit test class `Level1` in isolation mocking `Level2` interface and unit test class `Level2` in isolation mocking `Level3` interface. I am using `Nunit` as testing framework and `NMock` as mocking framework.

So far so good.

But, can I unit test first two levels of code **only mocking `Level3` interface without mocking `Level2`**? I mean I want to unit test class `Level1` without mocking `Level2` but mocking `Level3`. I wanted to do this because `Level3` class gets data from DB and I want to mock only this DB layer so that my whole project works just with mock db not with real db.

Comment: Yes. Most people would probably call it integration tests... Not sure what other feedback you are looking for...

Comment: The previous commentator is right: What is the question?

Comment: Okay, if thats called integration test. can you give me more info on how to do that test in my case? I mean how would you mock only level3 interface(db layer) and test level1 class., moreover all these classes are in the same solution, same project, so how would you call testing them as integration test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy:

```
// arrange
var mocks = new Mockery();
var mockLevel3 = mocks.NewMock<ILevel3>();
// now do some actual mocking here

var level2 = new Level2(mockLevel3);
var level1 = new Level1(level2);

// now do some act and assert stuff
```

It is an integration test in my opinion. It does not matter at this point if all of the classes are in the same assembly. Integration tests are not necessarily about bringing together some assemblies in a test.

Comment: hmm cool, that sounds what i want, let me test it with setting some expectations on level3.